# Synthesis from cyclic ketone to alcohol

Tags: reaction-mechanism, synthesis

How can I make the product in the picture below from cyclohexanone? I did Stork enamine synthesis, but it results in terminal primary alcohol. I need secondary alcohol with one more carbon atom at end. How to do that?

[image: 2-(3-hydroxybutyl)cyclohexan-1-ol]

Comment: How about a Michael addition of the cyclohexanone enolate to methyl vinyl ketone; follow this with a reduction of both carbonyls.

Comment: @ron How do you prevent Robinson annulation?

Comment: @Loong Good point, so you'd use an enamine (like the OP suggested) instead of the enolate and run the Michael addition under neutral conditions.